# How to maintain consistent model object in GET method , view and POST method in Spring boot+JSP

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-boot

here is my modal,

```
public class Mymodel{
    private String name;
    private Details details;
                             //getters and setters
    .........................
}
```

Here is my controller,

```
  @GetMapping("/form")
    public ModelAndView formGet(ModelMap model) {
        Mymodel mymodel = new Mymodel();

        .....bla bla bla....

        priceSearch.setDetails(anotherObj);

        model.addAttribute("mymodel", mymodel);
        return new ModelAndView("form",model);
    }

    @PostMapping("/form")
    public ModelAndView pricePost(
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("mymodel") Mymodel mymodel,
            BindingResult bindingResult,
            Model model) {
            //can see the inside data of mymodel object when debugging..

            modelAndView.setViewName("result");
            return modelAndView;
    }
```

here is my view,
form.jsp

```
   <form:form action="/form" commandName="mymodel"
                   method="POST" name="priceform"
                   enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">


                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="name">name:</label>
                            <form:input path="name"  cssClass="form-control input-sm" maxlength="20"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-10">

                                    <input type="submit"  value="Submit"
                                           class="btn btn-primary col-md-12" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </form:form>
```

note that Mymodel has two fields which is name and details , Details is a very complex class and I fill it inside the get method. Only thing I just want to update is name field from the form. but when I submit the form that detail data is not available. It seems like that Mymodel is not a continues object. How to make the connection. Even though not available in the form field I want to access details data from the post method.

Answer (score 0):

Use @SessionAttributes(COMMAND_NAME)